# Ubuntu 19.10 lags with 16GB RAM

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, lubuntu, 19.10, performance

I use my laptop mainly for work, programming and web browsing. It lags on Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit.

Specs:

- HP EliteBook 840 G5
- CPU: 1.8GHz quad core
- RAM: 16GB
- HDD: 500GB

Partition scheme:

[image]

It's strange that even when the CPUs and RAM are at 70% usage my laptop hangs and gets slow, it stays slow for 5 seconds and gets back to normal. Then it slows down. It lags even at times when I have not many programs open.

Resource stats during slowness:

[image]

I had Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.10 before I upgraded to 19.10. Could the lagging be caused by the Ubuntu 19.10 upgrade?

Comment: Please clarify your release; your heading says 19.10, your question says 16.10 and you tagged 14.04?  You also tagged lubuntu, and two of your pictures look more like their from a GNOME desktop.

Comment: Also, some program is consuming 100% cpu power of a core. Go to processes to check which programs are utilizing a lot of cpu clocks.

Comment: @guiverc The last screenshot is from Ubuntu 19.10 which salimsaid was using when this question was posted, so this question is not off topic.

Comment: I haven't tagged it off-topic @karel, my only comment related to contradictory detail (or what I considered to be contradictory)

Comment: @guiverc The question was never contradictory, only misunderstood by its reviewers. In the first revision the author of the question wrote "Could the slowness be caused by the ubuntu 19.10 upgrade?". That would have been an upgrade to 19.10 from either 14.04, 16.10 or both. I'm just mentioning it because it's essential to understanding this question. You can see what I'm driving at graphically in the chart in my answer to this question.

Comment: I am speaking from my own experience with a newer version (using a slower hdd a lot of times delays ubuntu booted it with nvme and it was way snappier without any bottlenecks or speed losses) Do note this does not have to be the case at all, it's simply what happened to me recently.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why your EliteBook with a quad core CPU and 16GB RAM should be lagging with these hardware specifications, so it seems likely that the lagging is caused by a botched release upgrade. I recommend a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on your laptop. In case you haven't installed Ubuntu lately, don't make the mistake of creating an unnecessary swap partition as the Ubuntu installer did in 14.04 and 16.10. Let the Ubuntu 20.04 installer create a swap file in the `/` partition for you as it does by default.

[Extended Security Maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/esm) (ESM) is a more logical way of scheduling the next release upgrade than recklessly skipping over releases when upgrading. With Canonical's free ESM Ubuntu 22.04 would be supported until April, 2032.

[image]